# HP LaserJet printer not recognized in 12.04 with hplip installed

Tags: printing, lubuntu

My LaserJet P1005 used to work fine after installing hplip in 11.10. Now it is not recognized when plugged in. No pop-up, nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved it. After installing hplip, all I had to do was run ’sudo hp-setup’ after connecting the printer. Tried it a few times without "sudo" and plugin install failed.

Comment: When I do that and select "Download" it just sits there thinking and never does anything.

Answer (score 3):

Download and install HPLIP directly from the HP OPEN SOURCE website.
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

Click on DOWNLOAD HPLIP.
Find the downloaded file and right click on it and select PERMISSIONS. Select MAKE EXECUTABLE. Click OK.

Right click on the file again and select OPEN then EXECUTE. Follow the instuctions.

*Reason it works is mainly because it detects and installs dependencies that the apt-get or software center version won't.

Comment: An alternative way to do this: After installing hplip, connect the printer, then use `sudo hp-setup` at the command line.